# Slick not working on multiple div elements created dynamically

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am using slick slider for sliding the divs. My div elements are created dynamically inside for loop and it is not working. I also included the required 4 files below are that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"><
```

and below is my function to create dynamic divs.

```
 function populateDataForMainPageSlide(data) {

  var numTimes = data.length;

  if (numTimes === 0) {
    var removeSlider = document.getElementById("sliderMainPage");
    removeSlider.style.display = "none";
    var removeHeading = document.getElementById("errorDivBlock");
    removeHeading.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
     if(data[i].shopInfo==null || data[i].shopInfo==undefined){
            continue;
          }
          var parent = document.getElementById("mainPageMask");
          var newVendorSlide = document.createElement("div");

          var funcString = "storeElementClickedLocalStorageVendor('" + data[i]._id + "');";
          var ref = document.createElement("a");
          ref.setAttribute("href", "vendorstore.html");
          ref.setAttribute("class", "w-inline-block");
          ref.setAttribute("onclick", funcString);
          newVendorSlide.setAttribute("style","height:300px;width:250px;border:1px solid ref;float:left")
          newVendorSlide.appendChild(ref);
          var header4 = document.createElement("h4");
          header4.setAttribute("class", "heading-52");
          header4.innerHTML = data[i].shopInfo.name;
          newVendorSlide.appendChild(header4);
          var bio = document.createElement("p");
          bio.innerHTML = data[i].shopInfo.description;
          newVendorSlide.appendChild(bio);

          parent.appendChild(newVendorSlide);
    }
  } 
}
```

Can anyone Please help me to solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's almost impossible to read your code with the current context provided, is it possible for you to try out ES6 templating strings? That might actually help you see your problem.

Comment: Don’t say it’s not working.  Explain what it does or does not do.

Comment: Actually, It is not adding buttons and dots & showing my all 5 divs on a same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear so i don't know why it is not working. **But Note**, you have to call slick method after your div's are rendered successfully. If you try to call slick before div's are redered on webpage then it will not work.

Thanks.